# send from netty server data to tcp client

Tags: java, tcp, netty

i'm trying to send data from netty channel to an tcp client, but the client does not receive any of it,

server:

```
 byte b=1;
incoming.writeAndFlush(b); // incoming it's Channel
```

client:

```
Socket cleint=new Socket("127.0.0.1",4444);
in=client.getInputStream();
in.read();
```

Comment: Maybe it'll be easier to get help if you provide more context and improve your code examples. Start debugging by using a tool like 'netcat'. That way you should be able to drill down and find out if there's a problem with your server or client code.

Comment: when i send from the client(tcp) to the server(netty-channel), the server receive the data with now problem; but the other direction i get now data